# Add service reference to a webservice that I do not have access to

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio

Weird question, I'm sure.

I want to make a small program that consumes a webservice. I don't have access to this webservice, from my developer machine, but on the client machine, I will have.

I know everything I need to know, about the service. I have it referenced in another program, and can copy/paste everything from there.

BUT, how do I add this reference, to my new project? Like, a manual override perhaps?

In the solution that already references it, I assume I could just copy the reference.cs file, but how do I get it into my new solution?

Comment: Add a dummy web-service reference and over-write the code for it ?

Comment: All you really need is the WSDL, that's the point of the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just create a new web service on the local machine using the code you have from the other soultion? Just add a reference to this for development.

Comment: I see no other possible solution, however, you might end up with a binding mismatch on the client box if you don't get it exactly correct.